# Why does push_back into vector<vector<int>> causing seg fault?

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault, push-back

Want to construct a Graph with adjacency list, but getting seg-fault when I add elements to `vector<vector<int>>`. `adj.size()` prints `5` which tells it has allocated memory, why the seg-fault in `addEdge()` method?

```
 #define V 5

    struct Edge {
        int src, dst;
    };

    void addEdge(vector<vector<int>> &adj, int u, int v)
    {
        adj[u].push_back(v);
    }

    void constructGraph(vector<vector<int>> &adj, vector<Edge> &edges)
    {

        for(Edge e : edges)
        {
            addEdge(adj, e.src, e.dst);
        }
    }

    int main()
    {
       vector<vector<int>> adj(V);

       vector<Edge> edges =
        {
            { 0, 1 }, { 1, 2 }, { 2, 0 }, { 2, 1 },
            { 3, 2 }, { 4, 5 }, { 5, 4 }
        };

        constructGraph(adj, edges);

       return 0;
    }
```

---

Comment: 5 is out of bounds on a vector of size 5. I think you meant `#define V 6`?

Comment: if you had used `.at()` it would tell you something like `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'`

Comment: @Andreas DM yes, just learnt that using .at() is always safer and is recommended over using [ ], the c programmer in me had to learn it the hard way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> void addEdge(vector<vector<int>> &adj, int u, int v)
> ```

```
{
    adj[u].push_back(v);
}
```

is incorrect.     The `operator[]()` for a vector ASSUMES the supplied index is valid.   If `u` is not valid, the behaviour is undefined.

In your code, the vector passed has five elements, and the last edge in `main()`

> ```
> vector<Edge> edges =
> ```

```
    {
        { 0, 1 }, { 1, 2 }, { 2, 0 }, { 2, 1 },
        { 3, 2 }, { 4, 5 }, { 5, 4 }               // note the last pair here
    };
```

will cause `addEdge()` to be called with `u` having a value of `5`.   That is one past the end.

While `#define V 6` will fix the problem, it doesn't protect `addEdge()` from being passed a bad value of `u`.   Instead I would implement `addEdge()` so it protects itself from bad data as follows.

```
void addEdge(vector<vector<int>> &adj, int u, int v)
{
    if (u < 0) return;                   // handle negative u
    if (u >= adj.size()) adj.resize(u+1);  //   resize if needed
    adj[u].push_back(v);
}
```

An even better approach would be to avoid using supplied data - such as the data in `edges` in your `main()` - as array indices at all.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Thanks for the guidance provided here, read up more on this and learnt that c++ language has protection built into it for these kinds of issues. Using .at() method protects the programmer from out-ob-bounds accesses.

```
void addEdge(vector<vector<int>> &adj, int u, int v)
{
    adj.at(u).push_back(v);
}
```

if you use adj.at(u) instead of adj[u], program exits little gracefully

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 5) >= this->size() (which is 5)
Aborted (core dumped)
```